# What Jars does Spark standalone have access to and when is it necessary to provide Jars through the SparkContext constructor?

Tags: maven, jar, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using Spark Streaming to connect to the Twitter sample api and I am retrieving the text of what tweets I get. The SparkContext is running standalone on my local machine.

```
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(
        "spark://[my network IP address]:7077", "StreamingTest",
        new Duration(1000), System.getenv("SPARK_PREFIX"), new String[]{...});
```

I have all of the jars I need to compile and run the code locally but when I call `.forEachRDD(new Function2<T, Time, Void>(){...})` on a`JavaReceiverInputDStream` that is derived from my Streaming Context I get a

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [my package].[my class]$1$1
```

which refers to the anonymous class provided to `.forEachRDD`.

I get around this issue by packaging the project in a jar and giving that as an argument for the SparkStreamingContext constructor but this seems odd for a few reasons:

1. Spark does not complain about other jars that I import into the project such as Twitter4J (added as a Maven dependency) so it must have inherent access to some jars,
2. To package the project so that it can pass itself to Spark seems too much like a bit of a workaround - there must be a more elegant solution,
3. A new copy of my jar is created in the Spark directory each time I run my code.

How can I determine what jars the Spark cluster has access to and when is it necessary/good practice to provide jars directly to the SparkContext constructor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your project has a dependency on third party jars, you need to include them as a comma separated list when you submit the program into the cluster. It is required to bundle your source into a jar file before submitting to a cluster.

Assume if your project structure is as below.

```
simpleapp
- src/main/java
   - org.apache.spark.examples
     -SimpleApp.java
- lib
  - dependent.jars (you can put all dependent jars inside lib   directory)
- target
   - simpleapp.jar (after compiling your source)
```

So you can use below command.

```
spark-submit --jars $(echo lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ',' ) --class org.apache.spark.examples.SimpleApp --master local[2]  target/simpleapp.jar
```

Further you can see the jar distribution using spark web console, go to your program -> Environment

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Harsha,

The [master-url]:4040/environment/ web-ui was very handy for debugging.
Note: job must be running for 4040 page to show anything, not just the Spark master/workers - which is something that caught me before.

I can confirm that there is a different env when I run my app using your command than if I had ran it from eclipse (eclipse has more), and they are mostly down as "System Classpath" not "added by user" as would be by adding the jars directly.

Using the web-ui I can confirm that the classes that my app looks for ARE in a jar on the classpath but I still get the exception...